# Excel vba script for special arrange in one column data

Tags: vba, excel

the script needed is to re arrange cell,

before

```
Human:Annie
[Fruit]=Banana
[Fruit]=Mango
[Fruit]=Apple
Human:Jack
[Fruit]=Apple
Human:John
[Fruit]=Mango
[Fruit]=Papay
```

after

```
Human:Annie [Fruit]=Banana
Human:Annie [Fruit]=Mango
Human:Annie [Fruit]=Apple
Human:Jack  [Fruit]=Apple
Human:John  [Fruit]=Mango
Human:John  [Fruit]=Papaya
```

Data is changes from 1 column to 2 column 
Before: Human and Fruit data on Column A
After: Human data on Column A and Fruit data on Column B

Comment: argh, formatting isn't holding in a comment, ill comment in an answer, please don't select my answer.

Comment: deleted my answer as it was not addressing your edit. I see from your edit I hadn't understood your question. what is the source of your data? are "Human:" and "Fruit]" part of the actual data? It seems like you should just want 2 columns of data, one labeled Humans and the other labled fruit. if this is example data then perhaps if you showed us the actual data it would help.

Comment: Human and [Fruit] are include in all data.. i want separate those data

Answer (score 1):

sorry but I don't have excel with me atm, only excel starter so no vba to figure it out for you but perhaps I can get you started. I'm posting this as an answer so I can format the code sample. hope this helps you get started.  just a hint how to get started. Someone else can provide a better answer for you later if you cant get it sorted.

```
Sub MoveValue()
Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Integer

x = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

With ActiveSheet
    For i = 2 To x
        If Instr(.Cells(i, 1),"Human:") = 1 Then
            .Cells(i, 2).Value = .Cells(i, 1).Value
        End If
        If Instr(.Cells(i, 2),"[Fruit]") = 1 Then
            .Cells(i, 3).Value = .Cells(i, 2).Value
        End If

    Next i
End With
```

End Sub

this will leave blank rows I expect so like I said, not a complete solution.